# using COPY command and wal_buffers

Tags: postgresql, bulkcopy

since `COPY` command runs inside a single transaction, if its WAL data doesn't fit into `wal_buffers`? for example if we are bulk importing from CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation [states](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/wal-configuration.html):

> There are two commonly used internal WAL functions: LogInsert and
>   LogFlush. LogInsert is used to place a new record into the WAL buffers
>   in shared memory. If there is no space for the new record, LogInsert
>   will have to write (move to kernel cache) a few filled WAL buffers.
>   This is undesirable because LogInsert is used on every database low
>   level modification (for example, row insertion) at a time when an
>   exclusive lock is held on affected data pages, so the operation needs
>   to be as fast as possible. What is worse, writing WAL buffers might
>   also force the creation of a new log segment, which takes even more
>   time. Normally, WAL buffers should be written and flushed by a
>   LogFlush request, which is made, for the most part, at transaction
>   commit time to ensure that transaction records are flushed to
>   permanent storage. On systems with high log output, LogFlush requests
>   might not occur often enough to prevent LogInsert from having to do
>   writes. On such systems one should increase the number of WAL buffers
>   by modifying the configuration parameter wal_buffers.

Which means for me that in such a situation the system will need more time to complete the `COPY` because of the writes.